# How to Add In App Purchase to iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have looked everywhere and I don't quite understand how to add In-App Purchases to an iPhone App. Can someone please explain with further detail exactly how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why not do some research, have a go, then come back and update your question with what you tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial explains exactly how to do what you're asking:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases